# Facebook test Push Notification "Device token does not match the environment"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, facebook

I have integrated Facebook analytics into my iOS application along with the facebook notifications.

When I try and send a test push notification to a device using the device token I get

> "The device token does not match the environment of the certificate.
>   For example, the device token is created by development build but the
>   uploaded push certificate is for production. Uploading a universal
>   push certificate is recommended."

The certificate and token are both development, and work perfectly through firebase.  Any ideas with this?

Comment: Did you find any solutions in it ? i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might using your **FCM token** as "device token" needed in facebook push campaign. **Use your "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" method's device token** for sending notification.

This code may help you, please try to put this "deviceTokenString" in facebook's device token field.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)  {
         // Convert token to string

let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

}
```